# Hot to pass params while starting node.js server on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, server, telegram-bot

I try to start node.js server on Heroku. It requires repo on Github. If I want to keep my token safe, how can i add it without including to commit on Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the following in your `package.xml`

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node flags server.js args whatever"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always add the token to heroku as an environment variable. You can do this through the UI within your heroku app under the Settings tab. Click on the "Reveal Config Vars" button. You can then access the token by using syntax "process.env.VARNAME".

Example:

If you set the Config Var in Heroku as "GIT_TOKEN = 12345"

```
let gitToken = process.env.GIT_TOKEN;
// use token to do your work.
```